# Атрибут "TITLE" у "SPAN"

Tags: html

Есть определённый текст:

> `<span class="" title="26.06.12 Название">Текст</span>`

Можно ли сделать перенос title на две строки, чтобы дата 26.06.12 была на первой строчке, а Название на второй? Как бы при наведении курсора на Текст появлялось две строки:

> 26.06.12
>
> Название

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если такое и есть, то это не кроссбраузерно.

Как вариант, использование **tooltip**.

Вот есть такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/L3g48b2d/

```
<span class="" title="26.06.12&#13;&#10;Название">Текст</span>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Только что в Интернете нашёл. Там тоже про ToolTip() написано.

Comment: обновил ответ